# Python - route selenium browser through a specific IP address

Tags: python, selenium, networking, ip, freebsd

I have multiple network interfaces (tun0, tun1 ...) and want to open several firefox browser instances in python, such that each one goes through a specific interface.

I can obtain the ip address of each interface with netifaces but have not found any way to 'attach' them to *browser = webdriver.Firefox(...)*. There is plenty of documentation on using *webdriver.DesiredCapabilities* and proxies but that isnt't what I'd like to achieve.

Ideally I'd really like to make it work at the python rather than OS level, since  the interfaces/ip addresses will change and this is driven by the python code.

Using FreeBSD 11.1 and Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works but you can download [selenium standalone server](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and run it with other network interface [like in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210992) and by assigning different ports (you can do it in command line while starting the server `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-version.jar -port 4545`) you can connect them individually. I don't know if network interface method works on browsers because driver launches a new process but I think it's worth to try, maybe it can help you to think the different ways.

Comment: Thanks Guven, I haven't given it a go yet but  since I haven't found a way in purely python I think I'll have to do something similar to netns.